# A cleardoublepage variant to always insert an empty left page (KOMA)

Tags: koma-script, clearpage

In KOMA Script we can find commands to modify the way empty pages are inserted, so that, e.g., chapters will always start on the right page.

The different commands can be found in [scrguide.pdf](https://komascript.de/~mkohm/scrguide.pdf) in section 3.13.

Many might know

```
\cleardoublepage
```

which ends the current section/chapter and inserts an empty left page if needed. No extra page is inserted if the chapter ends on a left page.
There are situations however, in which I want the new chapter to start on the right, with an empty left page. I found the following combination of commands to do the job:

```
\cleardoubleevenpage
\cleardoubleoddpage
```

[image]

Is there a better way to do that? I am basically looking for a command that

- finishes the current section/chapter, and
- inserts an empty page if on the right page, or
- inserts two empty pages if on the left page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! No, basically the cleardoublepage-commands are what you want. But what would you understand as "better way"?

Comment: My solution does the job but it seemed like misuse of the two commands. I guess I was more curious if I overlooked a single command dedicated to that functionality...

Comment: AFAIK KOMA-Script does not provide such a single command. But you can define a new command which uses the combination of the two macros.

Comment: Okay thanks guys. Maybe this thread will at least help others willing to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Although a combination of `\cleardoubleevenpage` and `\cleardoubleoddpage` does what you want, here is another way to achieve this.

It uses the `notespages` package and its command `\nppatchchapter`. This redefines `\chapter` so it works as if you write

```
\notespages[minoneempty]
\chapter...
```

With `\npunpatchchapter` the original definition of `\chapter` can be restored, and you may get no empty pages again.

With `\nppatchchapter{...}` and `\npunpatchchapter` you can switch this on and off several times in the document. The commands work from the next `\chapter` after these commands on.

If you want to have the minimum of one empty page only for a few chapters, instaed of using `\nppatchchapter` you can use `\notepages` directly before `\chapter` (as shown above).

Example code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{notespages}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% define a new option as abbreviation for the necessary option
\definenotesoption{minoneempty}{empty,multiple=2,minpages=1}
% for all chapters (would produce at least one empty page
% before first chapter in this example)
%\nppatchchapter{minoneempty}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A Chapter}
\section{A Section}
\lipsum[1-4]

\section{Another Section}
\lipsum[5-7]

% put command here to start later
\nppatchchapter{minoneempty}
\chapter{Another Chapter}
\section{A Section}
\lipsum[1-4]

\chapter{A third Chapter}
\section{A Section}
\lipsum[1-4]

\section{Another Section}
\lipsum[5-7]

\appendix
\chapter{First Appendix}
\lipsum

% disable it
\npunpatchchapter
\chapter{Second Appendix}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]